# If today is before 10th of Month, 15th of Month, 20th of Month

Tags: php, html

I simply want to apply a different class to an element if the current day is before a certain day of the month. I want to progressively increase the visibility as the month progresses to show urgency.

```
if today <= 10th of the current month
else if today <= 15th of the current month
else if today <= 20th of the current month
```

Comment: OK, seems pretty simple. So what have you tried and where'd you get stuck? Post your [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $dayOfMonth = date("d");  
 if($dayOfMonth <=10){

 }...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, my friend.